# Rails - Export DB to CSV not reading from translation file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rails-activerecord

I've seen a number of useful suggestions here but so far haven't been able to fix my problem. I'm creating a redmine plugin (ruby on rails) and I have a button that exports the db into a CSV file. That part works just fine.

My problem is that the column names in the csv file are not being translated don't seem to be changed by a call to `human_attribute_name`. Can anybody point out where i've gone wrong and help me correct it?

I mostly followed this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

app/models/person.rb

```
def self.to_csv(options={})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << User.attribute_names.map {|c| User.human_attribute_name(c)}
    # Could I instead use:
    # csv << User.human_attribute_names
    User.all.each do |user|
      csv << user.attributes.values
    end
  end
end
```

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        col1: "Column 1"
        col2: "Column 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution which seems to work:

app/models/user.rb

```
def self.to_csv(options={})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    @cols = User.attribute_names #[1..-1] to remove first column from output
    csv << @cols.map { |c| I18t.t c, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :user] }
    User.all.each do |user|
      csv << user.attributes.value_at(*@cols)
    end
  end
end
```